# ASP.NET MVC4 Deployed on Azure localization

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, azure-web-app-service

I've created an application in ASP.NET MVC4. Everything is ok on my Visual Studio 2012 IIS Server. The problem is when i publish it on Azure, then when i call `DateTime.Now` i got time from other time zone than mine and also when i want to display date : `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")` month name is in english. How can I specific culture (i.e. pl-PL) in a whole application?

I've tried `<Globalization Culture="pl-PL" UICulture="pl-PL" />` in web.config but with no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Azure runs all servers in UTC, which is appropriate.
- You should *never* call `DateTime.Now` in a server application.  That imposes the time zone of the server into the results.  There is no good reason for that - you should be able to deploy your application anywhere.  [Read more here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).
- Culture will only affect formatting, not time zones.  And only the `Culture` setting affects the output of `DateTime.ToString()`.  The `UICulture` doesn't matter (for this regard).
- It's not picking up your values from web.config because it is case sensitive and you are using the incorrect casing.  [Reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).  You need:

  ```
  <globalization culture="pl-PL" uiCulture="pl-PL" />
  ```

Comment: thank you for your excellent answer! it worked. Changed to Datetime.UtcNow